# Formatting SelectList Items

Tags: asp.net, html, selectlist

I was wondering if there was a way to format 2 strings in a selectlist and display them as following:

String begins with Item1 and spaces following it until 10 spaces are taken up followed by a Delimiter "|" and string 2

So all Selectlist items binded to a drop down list will be displayed as following

```
Item 1     |Name1
Item 2     |Name2
Item 55    |Name3
Item 500   |Name4
Item 100000|Name5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your description says that there should be two items on the same line, but your example shows an item and a name on each line. Which is right?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [System.String.PadRight()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx)

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i+= 5)
{
  string ItemString = "Item" + i.ToString().PadRight(10, ' ') + "|" + "Name" + i.ToString();
   SelectList.Items.Add(ItemString);
}
```

would result in

```
Item0     |Name0
Item5     |Name5
Item10    |Name10
```

Of course, you'll want to ensure that you're using a fixed-width font in the drop-down list

Comment: Thanks. Which fonts are considered fixed-width?

Answer (score 1):

You can use string format to build the text for the items:

```
string itemstring = string.Format("Item {0:0000000000}|Name {0}", itemNumber);
```

If you are using data binding to build the item, you can put the format expression in the DataTextFormatString to have ASP.NET format the items for you.

Comment: That's a good alternative.  I've used this as well, and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

best way to format it is:

```
string itemstring = String.Format("{0,-10}|{1}", item, name);
```